# Create WordPress plugins using Ruby

Tags: ruby, wordpress

I would like to create a WordPress plugin using Ruby (language). I understand that PHP is the primary server-side language used with WP. I don't know PHP, but know a great deal about Ruby, which is also a server-side language. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on previous experience and some reviews of similar questions on SO, there are ways you can call Ruby from within your Wordpress code. The simplest and elegant solution I've seen to this is here : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-api-to-connect-wordpress-with-ruby-on-rails--cms-21189

There are loads of arguments for going with both solutions at the same time, but probably the easiest read is this https://bernardic.ca/2012/07/08/rails-vs-wordpress/

Enjoy!